# Regex group capturing problem

Tags: c#, html, regex

If I had an html string containing this somewhere in the middle of it:

```
<img src="http://images.domain.com/Images/hello.jpg" alt="Failed to Load" />
```

What regex would I use in order to just obtain the name of the image file? i.e. hello.jpg

Currently I am using this:

```
(?<front>.*<img.*src="http://images.domain.com/Images/)(?<imgName>.*)"(?<end>.*)
```

However the value that it finds for the imgName group is:

```
hello.jpg" alt="Failed to Load
```

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest fix is to have the imgName group match anything except for quotes by changing .* to [^"]*:

```
(?<front>.*<img.*src="http://images.domain.com/Images/)(?<imgName>[^"]*)"(?<end>.*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see [why you shouldn't be trying this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Anyway, try `(?<imgName>.*?)` instead.